# Uniform convergence and boundedness

Tags: real-analysis

> Assume that $(f_n)$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $[a,b]$,
>   which converge uniformly. Prove that $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded,
>   i.e., there exists $M \ge 0$ such that, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and
>   any $x \in [a,b]$, $|f_n(x)| \le M$.

EDIT: Here is my attempt, I used the definition of uniform limit and the extreme value theorem, could someone please confirm if my arguments are valid?

We know that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ and each $f_n$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Then, by the continuity of the uniform limit, $f$ is also continuous on $[a,b]$. By the Extreme Value Theorem, there exists a value $M_0 \ge 0$ such that $|f(x)| \le M_0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Since $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to $f$, then for $\epsilon = 1$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < 1$ whenever $n \ge N$ and for all $x \in [a,b]$. By the triangle inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
|f_n(x)| = |f_n(x) - f(x) + f(x)| \le |f_n(x) - f(x)| + |f(x)| < 1 + M_0
\end{align*}
for all $n \ge N$ and for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Note that there are only a finite number of terms in the sequence, $(f_n)$, before the $N$th term. Since each $f_n$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then by the Extreme Value Theorem for $n = 1, 2, \cdots, N-1$, there exists a value $M_n \ge 0$ such that $|f_n(x)| \le M_n$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Now set $M = \max\{M_1, M_2, \cdots, M_{N-1}, 1+M_0 \}$, then it follows that there exists $M \ge 0$ such that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for any $x \in [a,b]$, $|f_n(x)| \le M$.

Comment: Please show us what u have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is right.

However you don't need to use the continuity of $f$.

By uniform continuity, there exists some $N$ such that $n \geq N \Rightarrow \forall x\in [a,b], |f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq 1$

By triangle inequality, for $n \geq N$ and $x\in [a,b]$,$ |f_n(x)|\leq|f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f_N(x)|+|f_N(x)|$

Hence, for $n \geq N$ and $x\in [a,b]$ $ |f_n(x)|\leq 2+|f_N(x)|$

To finish the proof you only need to rely on the Extreme Value Theorem applied to $f_1,\ldots f_N$

Answer (score 0):

If not, for every $j \in \mathbb{N}$ there exist $n_j \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_j \in [a,b]$ with $|f_{n_j}(x_j)| \geq j$. Up to a subsequence, $x_j \to x_\infty \in [a,b]$, and by uniform convergence $f_{n_j}(x_j) \to f(x_\infty)$.
Therefore $|f(x_\infty)| \geq +\infty$, a contradiction.